# How to print char[,] in C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace cis237_assignment2
{
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main entry point for the program.
    /// You are free to add anything else you would like to this program,
    /// however the maze solving part needs to occur in the MazeSolver class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Starting Coordinates.
        const int X_START = 1;
        const int Y_START = 1;

        // The first maze that needs to be solved.
        // Note: You may want to make a smaller version to test and debug with.
        // You don't have to, but it might make your life easier.
        char[,] maze1 =
        { { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' } };

        // Create a new instance of a mazeSolver.
        MazeSolver mazeSolver = new MazeSolver();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", maze1);



        // Create the second maze by transposing the first maze
        char[,] maze2 = transposeMaze(maze1);

        // Solve the original maze.
        mazeSolver.SolveMaze(maze1, X_START, Y_START);

        // Solve the transposed maze.
        mazeSolver.SolveMaze(maze2, X_START, Y_START);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will take in a 2 dimensional char array and return
    /// a char array maze that is flipped along the diagonal, or in mathematical
    /// terms, transposed.
    /// ie. if the array looks like 1, 2, 3
    ///                             4, 5, 6
    ///                             7, 8, 9
    /// The returned result will be:
    ///                             1, 4, 7
    ///                             2, 5, 8
    ///                             3, 6, 9
    /// The current return statement is just a placeholder so the program
    /// doesn't complain about no return value.
    /// 
    /// It is important that you return a "new" char array as the transposed maze.
    /// If you do not, you could end up only solving the transposed maze.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mazeToTranspose"></param>
    /// <returns>transposedMaze</returns>
    static char[,] transposeMaze(char[,] mazeToTranspose)
    {
        //Write code her to create a transposed maze.
        return new char[1, 1];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you area asking help with? Are you trying to write the maze to the console? What happens when you try? You just pasted your homework assignment, I don't think this is the place for someone to do your homework.

Comment: You have a loop in a loop, each with its own loop variable (e.g. `i` and `j`), and then you print the character at each location in the 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're asking on how to iterate over a [Multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)..

The link could provide a great help for you, however, in short, if you know it's 2-D, it's pretty straight-forward

```
///char[,] arr2D
for (int i=0; i<arr2D.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<arr2D.GetLength(1); j++)
      Console.Write((j>0)?", ":"" + arr2D[i, j]);
    Conole.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's how to print it in one line of code.

```
Console.Write(new string(maze1.Cast<char>().SelectMany( (c, i) => (i + 1) % (maze1.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) == 0 ? new[] { c, '\r', '\n' } : new[] { c } ).ToArray()));
```

Or to spread it out a little:

```
Console.Write
(
    new string 
    (
        maze1.Cast<char>().SelectMany
        (
            (c, i) => (i + 1) % (maze1.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) == 0 
                    ? new[] { c, '\r', '\n' } 
                    : new[] { c }
        )
        .ToArray()
    )
);
```

I wouldn't recommend writing it this way in a commercial code base, but it might impress someone.